# Homepage not showing right on iPad - CSS issue causing width to be wrong

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

This site: http://www.firearmspolicy.org

On an iPad, the homepage reacts differently to the iPad than the rest of the site. On the rest of the site, the page has a small amount of margin where you can see the background of the page; and the menu is slightly smaller, etc.. On the homepage, all that nice re-sizing seems to be broken, and instead I get about 30px(?) or so on the right of the homepage that shows off-screen to the right on the iPad... (Basically, you can scroll the page to the left and see the extra space to the right.

It's ONLY an issue on the homepage of the site, and I'm just missing something. Hopefully a fresh set of eyes can help.

Answer (score 0):

Is that responsive website or it's causing problems even if it's not?
If it's responsive site, check if you have

```
<meta name="viewport" width="width-device-width" />
```

and in CSS, try to count the percentage of the width if it's not more than 100%, then I would check if you have @media query wrote good. It should be like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 000px) and (max-width: 000px) {
      /* STYLES for the device with the width from entered interval */
}
```

000px --> your sizes ;)

Comment: What I don't get is how every other page is correct.... I know there's a lot of >940px things, but, the site was changed from a responsive to a static version recently. All other pages work, just not the homepage. So, I'd assume that there's just one element on that page that's causing the issue.

Comment: Apparently, it's messed up in the reverse on an iPhone... :(

Comment: Well, maybe you can send me a mail with your HTML and CSS file. I can maybe help somehow.. but I don't know what can be the issue without seeing a code :( .. my mail is: info@grafcomp.net

Comment: I think there will be like one mistake, nothing special at all... I had a lot of issues like that with my friend's site that I was doing last week.. I was surprised when people show me my mistakes.. :D

Comment: Oops, sry, didn't see your answer there ;) So have a nice day or night, sir. Wish you all good with this site ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm just a moron... Cached copies of the pages were wrong. Everything working now.. Oops!